# Как сделать, что бы было как в jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

С jquery например можно написать такую запись:

```
$("#page1").css({display: 'inherit'}).animate({"right":"+=581px"}, 1500);
```

Сначала присвоится css, потом выполниться анимация, а как на чистом js сделать подобное?

Например:

```
function myFunc() {........}
document.getElementById("myID").myFunc().myFunc();
```

Чтоб к элементу с id myID применилась какая то моя myFunc() и потом по завершению применилась она же второй раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите через prototype для Element метод myFunc и будет Вам счастье
(метод MyFunc должен возвращать сам элемент)

```
Element.prototype.myFunc=function(){
    this.id+='bla';
    return this;
}
document.getElementById("myID").myFunc().myFunc();
```

в результате id элемента будет 'myIDblabla'

Comment: можно пример, с prototype ещё не сталкивался

Comment: Element.prototype.myFunc=function(){
         // делаем, то что надо
         return(this);
    }

Comment: это не совсем то, как нибудь можно именно такой записью document.getElementById("myID").myFunc().myFunc();  ?

Comment: Я описал как правильно объявить функция myFunc, чтобы она работала в цепочке вызовов в стиле jQuery (вместо объявления функции в стиле function myFunc(){...})
добавил в ответ